# getElementbyId Return Null external js folder

Tags: javascript

Now I'm going nuts because this error seems so simple and yet I do not understand.

there is a div in here which `id = "origin"`.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Enter short, descriptive title here</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="all">

        @import url("style.css");   

    </style>
</head>
<body id="body">
    <div id="curtain">

    <p>Welcome to your Destination</p>

    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="top">
        <h1>Someting can go in here</h1>

        </div>
        <div id="divider"></div>
            <div id="bottom">               

                <div id="origin">Origin</div>
                <h2 id = "the_destination">Destination</h2>
                <div id="the_brackets">(The Brackets)</div>
                <div id="the_price">$249</div>
                <div id="the_cta">BOOK NOW</div>

            </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascipt">

      window.onload = function(){
        dynamicText();
    }
    </script>

</body>
```

and here is the js which is returning null in a script.js file in the root folder for experimental purposes.

```
function dynamicText() {
    var origin = document.getElementById("origin").textContent;
    alert("The Origin is: " + origin);
    console.log(origin);
}

window.onload = function(){
dynamicText();
}
```

for some reason, this is returning **null**. im simply trying to get the value where       id ="origin". thats all im trying to do and yet this is giving me a 
"null" error. I dont see where i have gone wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<div>` doesn't have a `value` property. Try accessing `textContent` instead.

Also you need to make sure the script runs after the elements are generated.

1. Move the `<script>` to the end of `<body>`
2. Use [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) and call the function or wrap the code that is referencing the DOM in it.

Comment: @Tushar yes, had to go away for a call... thanks for the edit :)

Comment: so just above the </body> is that where i put <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

Comment: @Jacob yes. So that browser will encounter and run the script after it's done parsing all the elements above...

Comment: @Jacob Right, also use `textContent` or `innerHTML` on `var origin = document.getElementById("origin").textContent`

Comment: ok i modified the code to replicate what i have locally and im still getting the same issue

Comment: @Jacob you're assigning the variable to null using `=`. See [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xez5c8es/)

Comment: thank you very much, i thought hell yeah! iits working then i copied the html over to my file between the body tags and in the js file i put that js in and im still getting the same issue. i dont know what im doign wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling the function before the `div` is there. Put the function call in the `onload` function.

```
window.onload = function(){
    dynamicText();
}
// tested on win7 with chrome 46+
```

Like this the function will be called, when the html is finished "rendered" and `getElementById` not return `null`.

Apart from that `div` dont have a `value` propert use `innerText` or `innerHTML` or ...

```
document.getElementById("origin").innerText;// or similar
```

**Update :**
*info out of the comments*

Running example from jsFiddle [demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/ywoLuxcL)

> **onload** was omitted since jsFiddle puts the code into the *"onload event"* anyway

Comment: No, `onload`, use `DOMContentLoaded`

Comment: In any case the problem is, that the script is called before the html element is rendered, when and how to trigger the script is, a style decision.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nshjqLkp/ here is a js fiddle which seems to still not work after your suggestions. maybe i have missed something

Comment: @Jacob i just also wrote a js fiddle this one works .https://jsfiddle.net/ywoLuxcL please try this.

Comment: In the jsfiddle you dont need the onload since all the code will be run on *onload*. :)

Comment: thank you im not sure what i have done wrong but im still not getting anything?

Comment: depends on the Browser, maybe you have disabled the alert windows or so, a security feature, but i worked om my ipad and now on my PC.